# Using autocorrelation plots to choose the number of inputs for a neural network predicting time series

Tags: time-series, neural-networks, model-selection, autocorrelation, lags

A neural network applied to time series needs to have the number of input nodes defined. Each input is applied to a time point previous to the current point being predicted. If $D$ is the number of past time points taken, how is this number determined? Can the autocorrelation function be used for the lag correlation plot to give insight as to the best number of previous values to use? If so how?

Comment: This seems reasonable, isn't it the way that AR and MA terms are determined in an ARIMA? http://www.duke.edu/~rnau/411arim3.htm

Comment: @B_Miner, I guess it is, but neural networks are not statistical so I don't know the framework or process for choosing the lag.

Comment: It sounds like you're using a feed-forward network, but typically one would use a [tag:rnn] for sequential data.